# Subversion post commit hook SSL certificate error 'certificate issued for different hostname'

Tags: svn, azure, ssl, visualsvn

I have setup VisualSVN inside a new VM using Windows Azure (SLAVE). I have copied an existing repository manually from our internal server (MASTER) to it and I can see both repos on my client machine (CLIENT) using TortoiseSVN.

From CLIENT, MASTER is accessed using

```
svn://MASTER/repo....
```

while SLAVE is accessed using

```
https://SLAVE.cloudapp.net:8443/svn/repo....
```

I have updated the post commit hook on our internal server (MASTER, running Collabnet Edge) to sync to the Azure server (SLAVE running VisualSVN). When I first ran this sync batch file from within our internal server MASTER using remote desktop it prompted me with a certificate error to '(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily ...etc' and I chose 'p' (permanently). From this point on, all sync actions are fine when run on MASTER using remote desktop.

When performing a commit from my client machine CLIENT though, this updates the repo on MASTER as usual but then I get a TortoiseSVN error showing:

```
Error validating server certificate for
 'https://myserver.cloubapp.net:8443'
 - This certificate is not issued by a trusted authority....
 The certificate hostname does not match...
svnsync:E175002 OPTIONS of 
'https://myserver.cloubapp.net:8443/svn/myrepo' 
server certificate verification failed: certificate
 issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted
 (https://myserver.cloudapp.net:8443)
```

I presume that this error is an SSL error when MASTER tries to communicate with VisualSVN on SLAVE. So, I used VisualSVN to export the certificate on MASTER and I've imported it into CLIENT, putting it into 'trusted root certification authorities' but this has not stopped the error.

I've also tried adding:

```
--trust-server-cert --non-interactive
```

to the svnsync line in my hook but I still get

```
....certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted ....
```

I looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108914/subversion-server-ssl-certificate-verification-failed-and-other-reasons) which seemed possibly relevant but I'm very weak on this certificate stuff. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VisualSVN Server 3.5.4 and found similar problem but for me it throws following error on CLIENT when submit changes

```
svnsync: E230001: Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate has expired
```

It is my commercial certificate has expired. I solved it by

```
create a new self-signed certificate on SLAVE's VisualSVN Certificate setting
*the Common name must matches your SLAVE domain name
```

and adding on MASTER

```
--trust-server-cert --non-interactive
```